# How do I do force http for some files in web.config file

Tags: php, asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I have some files which needs to be in http .I tried the following code but doesn't work. 
How can I set force HTTP for the pages page1,page2 in web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Force HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)/page1.php" ignoreCase="false"/>
                                <match url="(.*)/page2.php" ignoreCase="false"/>
                <conditions> 
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON" ignoreCase="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Iam working in IIS 7 web server for PHP application in windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your rule to:

```
<rule name="Force HTTP" stopProcessing="true">  
  <match url="^page[12].php(.*)" />  
  <conditions>  
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />  
  </conditions>  
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />  
</rule>
```

The `url="^page[12].php(.*)"` will match any url starting with `page1.php` or `page2.php`.
The action redirects the request to `https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}` where `{R:0}` contains the requested path.

Comment: Thanks...:) .
I meant for different pages like (onpage, anoher page) . I changed the match tag as <match url="^onepage.php(.*)|^another.php(.*)" />. Also the redirection is to http instead of https. It works fine now . Once again thank you very much.

Comment: @suneesh Right, the redirect to `HTTPS` was a typo!! Sorry :)